# OpenCV HSV: iOS vs Python and C++

Tags: ios

I am converting an image [(link is here)](https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/0U533TaP_ueh9tlUIYcUoLhbZbw=/420x240/https://public-media.si-cdn.com/filer/38/ee/38ee7aaa-abbb-4c60-b959-4b1c5c8c6989/axgpay.jpg) from BGR to HSV with OpenCV 3.4.4. In both python and C++, the results are exactly the same, but iOS produces different values. The point of the question is that hue is different in iOS while Python and C++ produces the exactly the same values.

In python

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("monkey.jpg")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
print(hsv[0][0])
# [30,132,135]
```

In C++

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat image,hsv;
image = imread("monkey.jpg")
cvtColor(image,hsv,COLOR_BGRHSV);
cout << hsv.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << endl;
// [30,132,135]
```

Both Python and C++ produce [30,132,135] at the location (0,0) (top left corner).

However, in Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.0, the first value, hue, is 90 in the following OpenCVWrapper.mm file:

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

+ (void)getHSV:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    cv::Mat hsv;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);
    cv::cvtColor(mat, hsv, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    
    std::cout << hsv.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << std::endl;

@end
```

The result is [90,132,135]. The hue has the different value. I noticed that this is the case throughout the image. How is this happening?

P.S. I'm very new to OpenCV and iOS. I'm not so sure about the libraries loaded at the top of OpenCVWrapper.mm file.

Comment: Most HSV hue ranges are 0 to 360. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV. I am not sure what Apple uses. But OpenCV uses 0 to 180. (Scaled by 1/2 of 0 to 360 to keep the values in the 8-bit range). See the comment under the blue line at https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html. However, I would have thought that would mean

Comment: For the particular image I used, I checked the range with for-loop in iOS OpenCV wrapper implementation. Hue spans 0 - 179. I have to double-check on this with an official documentation from Apple if it exists. If the hue range is the same with OpenCV, why it's 90 in iOS OpenCV wrapper while it's 30 in the other languages?

Comment: Other languages use 0 to 360, not 0 to 180.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post an answer to my own question.

When we read an image as UIImage in iOS, it's RGB, not BGR. It's simple but opposite to when we usually read images with cv2.imread in python/C++. So what I needed to do was:

```
UIImage -> RGB -> BGR -> HSV
```

Then, all three(Python, C++, Objective-C/C++) have the same [30,132,135]

This is my code in OpenCVWrapper.mm file:

```
+ (void)getHSV:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat matRGB, matBGR, hsv;
    UIImageToMat(image,matRGB);
    //std::cout << mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << std::endl;
    cv::cvtColor(matRGB,matBGR,cv::COLOR_RGB2BGR);
    //std::cout << matBGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << std::endl;
    cv::cvtColor(matBGR,hsv,cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    std::cout << hsv.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0) << std::endl;
}
```